# code for converting sms text to speech (audio voice) in android

Tags: android, audio, sms, text-to-speech, voice-recognition

Can any one give me idea or downloaded code about notification about receiving sms msg and convert this sms into audio when i click on button.

Answer (score 1):

Try [this](http://www.apriorit.com/our-company/dev-blog/227-handle-sms-on-android) link for receiving sms.

After parsing the sms message use android text to speech engine from [here](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-text-to-speech-tutorial/).

Comment: thnks...dude...it helps me a lot